# How to Determine Tablespace from ROWID if data_object_id is not Unique?

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning, tablespace, rowid, data-files

If the `data_object_id` is not unique within a database as Tanel Poder [demonstrated](https://tanelpoder.com/2008/10/21/transportable-tablespaces-and-rowid-uniqueness/) (albeit from 2008), then how does Oracle uniquely determine the tablespace from the `ROWID` in order to make use of the `ROWID`'s `relative_fno`?

For example, a global index on a partitioned table whose partitions are in different tablespaces would require the extended `ROWID` in the global index to uniquely identify the tablespace of the row to which the index entry refers.

I am using Oracle Enterprise Edition 19c, but I suspect the answer only requires Oracle 8+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poder's article demonstrates `ROWID` duplication within a *database*, but not within a *table*. When using a `ROWID`, whether from an index or explicitly in a `WHERE` clause, Oracle knows what table its coming from. That narrows down the possible reference of the `data_object_id` to only one possible partition/segment, which means only one possible tablespace.

The example Poder gives of a potential problem is the unrealistic scenario of a program using `ROWID` as a kind of global identifier across tables with a uniqueness relied on by user code, which nobody should be doing. (Not only is it nonsensical to attempt a global identifier across entities, but `ROWID` should never be used by code outside of the lifetime of the cursor that fetched it, let alone as a permanent identifier. It's volatile, and will change if the row moves due to update of a partition key column or partitions are split, merged or exchanged, or if a DBA or scheduled management script does any move/reorg/compression work.) So it's a "problem" that probably nobody, or nearly nobody, will have run into since this was introduced in Oracle 8.

Comment: Thanks.  I was supposing one could use Tanel's technique, but for only one of the tablespaces of a partitioned table whose partition segments were not all stored in the same tablespace.  I now realize one is required to either transport all or none of the partitions of a partitioned table [askTom.com](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=use-transportable-tablespace-to-archive-old-data).  
``ORA-39901: Partitioned table ... is partially contained in the transportable set.``

Therefore, I no longer have doubts about the ``data_object_id`` being unique with respect to a table.